# Accessing parent values via foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, dbcontext

Models:

```
public class School
{
    public int ID {Get;set;}
    public string SchoolName {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms {get;set;}
}

public class Room
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string RoomName {get;set;}

    public int SchoolID {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("SchoolID")]
    public virtual School School {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Computer> Computers {get;set;}
}

public class Computer
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string ComputerName {get;set;}

    public int RoomID {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("RoomID")]
    public virtual Room Room {get;set;}
}
```

So, I have a Computer object and trying to access the School name, like:

```
Computer myComp = context.Computers.FirstOrDefault();
string SchoolName = myComp.School.SchoolName;
```

And I am getting a null object in return. Can someone point me in the right direction as to why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When querying your object you need to specifically tell the Entity Framework that you want to include the related object.  Here is how you can do that using [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

```
Computer myComp = context.Computers.Include(c => c.School).FirstOrDefault();
```

Make sure you include the namespace where that method lives:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```